# How to allocate memory for lines of a file in C?

Tags: c

I have created functions that are supposed to find the number of lines in a file (find_numlines()) and a function to read the lines of the file into char*** lines (read_lines()).  The rest of the functions in my main were provided so the problems are not in those functions.

read_lines.c (UPDATED):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "read_lines.h"


int findnum_lines(FILE* fp){

  int num_lines = 0;
  int line;

  line = getc(fp);
  if (line != EOF) {
    num_lines++;
    do {
      if (line == '\n') {
        num_lines = num_lines + 1;
      }
      line = getc(fp);
    }
    while (line != EOF);
  }
  rewind(fp);
  return num_lines;
}


void read_lines(FILE* fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines){

  int i;

  (*lines) = malloc(*num_lines * sizeof(char*));

  for (i=0; i < *num_lines; i++)
  {
    (*lines)[i] = malloc(1000);
    (*lines)[i][0] = '\0';
    fgets((*lines)[i], 1000, fp);
  }
}
```

main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "read_lines.h"


void print_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i){
        printf("%d. %s", i+1, lines[i]);
    }
}

void free_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i){
        free(lines[i]);
    }

    if(lines != NULL && num_lines > 0){
        free(lines);
    }

}

FILE* validate_input(int argc, char* argv[]){

    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Not enough arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        printf("Unable to open file: %s\nEnding program.\n", argv[1]);
        //fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }

    return fp;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);

    num_lines = findnum_lines(fp);
    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

read_lines.h :

```
#ifndef READ_LINES
    #define READ_LINES
    #include <stdio.h>
    void read_lines(FILE* fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines);
    int findnum_lines(FILE* fp);
#endif
```

Whenever I input a file the `find_numlines()` returns the correct number of lines but something goes wrong in the `read_lines()` because `lines` is still `NULL`.

The example file is `normal.txt` :

```
Hello Class
This is what I would call a normal file
It isn't very special
But it still is important
```

The ouptut should be:

```
1. Hello Class
2. This is what I would call a normal file
3. It isn't very special
4. But it still is important
```

Comment: When you ask what is wrong with code, always include a [mcve]. It should be a **complete** example that other people can compile. You should test that by compiling in a directory separate from your usual work. In the code posted in the question, `#include "read_lines.h"` will not work for other people because they do not have that file, and the `read_lines` function is missing a `}`.

Comment: In order for `lines` to change from `NULL`, something has to assign a value other than `NULL` to it. Nothing in the code posted does that. Something would need to allocate memory, as by calling `malloc`, and assign the return value from `malloc` to `lines`.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the "line-table" which contains pointers to the starts of the lines and also for each contents of the lines.
In the shown code it should be done in the function read_lines.
But it is not the best style to use triple-pointers though it should work.

Comment: @MiCo I added malloc but I don't believe I did it correctly because nothing is printing.

Comment: Note:three-star programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code I added the `rewind` command (mentioned by xing) and the memory allocation for **each** line and the "line table". Further improvements were performed in the code for counting the lines and the error handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int findnum_lines(FILE* fp){

  int num_lines = 0;
  int c;

  c = getc(fp);
  if (c != EOF) {
    num_lines++;
    do {
        if (c == '\n') {
            num_lines = num_lines + 1;
        }
        c = getc(fp);
    }
    while (c != EOF);
  }
  rewind(fp);
  return num_lines;
}

void read_lines(FILE* fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines){

  int i;

  // allocate memory for pointers to start of lines
  (*lines) = malloc(*num_lines * sizeof(char*));

  for (i=0; i < *num_lines; i++)
  {
    (*lines)[i] = malloc(1000);
    (*lines)[i][0] = '\0'; // terminate for the case that last line does not contain characters
    fgets((*lines)[i], 1000, fp); // read up to 999 characters and terminate string
  }

}

void print_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i){
        printf("%d. %s", i+1, lines[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void free_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i) {
        if (lines[i]!=NULL) {
            free(lines[i]);
        }
    }
    if (lines != NULL){
        free(lines);
    }
}

FILE* validate_input(int argc, char* argv[]){

    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Not enough arguments entered.\n");
    }
    else if (argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments entered.\n");
    }
    else {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (fp == NULL){
            printf("Unable to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        }
    }
    return fp;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        num_lines = findnum_lines(fp);
        read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
        print_lines(lines, num_lines);
        free_lines(lines, num_lines);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way:
There is no need to pass num_lines as pointer to function read_lines.
You can elimante one level of (de-)referencing for the lines variable if the read_lines functions returns a double-pointer to char (instead of passing a triple-pointer by argument to it).

Comment: I posted my updated code & my new output!  I am not sure why an extra line is being printed.

Comment: Sorry just realized there was an extra empty line in my text file! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. - If my answer was useful for you, you may want up-vote it with the small arrow on the left. ;-)